# Multiple radio button groups in the same form not retaining the styling

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a form that has three groups of radio buttons. If I click on any of the options in group 1, it highlights green If I then click on any of the options in group 2, it highlights green but turns off the selected option in group 1.

It's the same for group 3. Having read a number of posts regarding multiple radio groups in one form I have not found a solution. Where am I going wrong?

Group 1

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Vertical button group">
<button type="radio" class="btn btn-primary-RoomLevel btn-xs" name="RoomLevel" id="RoomLevel_1" value="1">Name, text and logo</button>
<button type="radio" class="btn btn-primary-RoomLevel btn-xs" name="RoomLevel" id="RoomLevel_2" value="2">Name and logo</button>
<button type="radio" class="btn btn-primary-RoomLevel btn-xs" name="RoomLevel" id="RoomLevel_3" value="3">Name only</button>
<button type="radio" class="btn btn-primary-RoomLevel btn-xs" name="RoomLevel" id="RoomLevel_4" value="4">Logo only</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Group 2

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Vertical button group">
<button type="radio" class="btn btn-primary-DisplayLevel btn-xs" name="DisplayLevel" value="1" id="DisplayLevel_1" value="1">Name, text and logo</button>
<button type="radio" class="btn btn-primary-DisplayLevel btn-xs" name="DisplayLevel" value="1" id="DisplayLevel_2" value="2">Name and logo</button><br/>
<button type="radio" class="btn btn-primary-DisplayLevel btn-xs" name="DisplayLevel" value="1" id="DisplayLevel_3" value="3">Name only</button><br/>
<button type="radio" class="btn btn-primary-DisplayLevel btn-xs" name="DisplayLevel" value="1" id="DisplayLevel_4" value="4">Logo only</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Group 3

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Vertical button group">
<button type="radio" class="btn btn-primary-BoardLevel btn-xs" name="BoardLevel" value="1" id="BoardLevel_1" value="1">Display On</button>
<button type="radio" class="btn btn-primary-BoardLevel btn-xs" name="BoardLevel" value="1" id="BoardLevel_2" value="2">Display Off</button><br/>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.btn-group-vertical {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #999999;  
}

.btn-primary-RoomLevel {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #E4E4E4;
    border-color: #999999;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    width: 175px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.btn-primary-RoomLevel:focus,
.btn-primary-RoomLevel.focus {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #93FF93;
    border-color: #999999;
}
.btn-primary-RoomLevel:hover {
    color: #CC0000;
    background-color: #D9FFD9;
    border-color: #999999;
}

.btn-primary-BoardLevel {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #E4E4E4;
    border-color: #999999;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    width: 175px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.btn-primary-BoardLevel:focus,
.btn-primary-BoardLevel.focus {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #93FF93;
    border-color: #999999;
}
.btn-primary-BoardLevel:hover {
    color: #CC0000;
    background-color: #D9FFD9;
    border-color: #999999;
}

.btn-primary-DisplayLevel {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #E4E4E4;
    border-color: #999999;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    width: 175px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.btn-primary-DisplayLevel:focus,
.btn-primary-DisplayLevel.focus {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #93FF93;
    border-color: #999999;
}
.btn-primary-DisplayLevel:hover {
    color: #CC0000;
    background-color: #D9FFD9;
    border-color: #999999;
}
```

Comment: you are using `focus` there can be only one dom in the HTML that's in focus.

Comment: @Matan Sanbira Hi Thanks for spotting that, I will try and solve the issue.

Comment: You are using wrong html attribute inside button tag `<button type="radio">` this is invalid html because of button has `type="button"` or `type="submit"` not `type="radio"` so if you want to use radio button then use like this **<input type="radio" name="group1">**.